# Wikitude cordova plugin camera black screen showing only Trial word(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, cordova, hybrid, wikitude

Hello everyone i've been stuck for the whole day trying to figure out why is the camera view not showing. It only shows black with the world trial.

Its supposed to be showing the camera live feed along with the watermarks trial 
here is the documentation

> [Wikitude Cordova Plugin Reference](https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/phonegap/reference.html#javascript-api)

Here is a screen shot

> [Image one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHn97.png), [Image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiefB.png)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <script src="https://www.wikitude.com/libs/architect.js"></script>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>


    <button style="width: 50%; margin-top: 50%; margin-left: 25%; font-size:50px" id="cam">Start Augmented</button>
    <button style="width: 50%; margin-top: 55%; margin-left: 25%; font-size:50px" id="clo">Close</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var wikitudePlugin;
$(document).on('deviceready',function(){
    wikitudePlugin = cordova.require("com.wikitude.phonegap.WikitudePlugin.WikitudePlugin");
    var requiredFeatures = [ "2d_tracking", "geo" ];
    var arExperienceUrl = "www/index.html";
    var startupConfiguration = { "camera_position": "back"};

    $('#cam').click(function(){
        wikitudePlugin.isDeviceSupported(function(){
            wikitudePlugin.loadARchitectWorld(
            function(url){
                alert("Success");
                wikitudePlugin.show();
            },
            function(err){
                alert("Error"+err);
            },
            arExperienceUrl,
            requiredFeatures,
            startupConfiguration
            );
        },
        function(){
            alert("Not Supported and cp mo bulok haha");
        },
        requiredFeatures);
    });

    $('#clo').click(function(){
        wikitudePlugin.hide();
    });
});

$(document).on('pause',function(){
   wikitudePlugin.onPause();
});

$(document).on('resume',function(){
  wikitudePlugin.onResume();
});

$(document).on('backbutton',function(){
  wikitudePlugin.onBackButton();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the trial watermark is being rendered correctly the Wikitude SDK seems to be running. My guess is that your app does not have permission to access the camera.

If that should not be the case, I'd prefer to continue this conversation in the Wikitude forums. SO does not seem to me to be the best place for remote debugging an issue such as this.

https://support.wikitude.com/support/home

Comment: thank you for the answer. But i think the camera is open because when i alert the `AR.hardware.camera.enabled` it returns true